# javafx bind to observablelist item change event not working

Tags: javafx

say i have an application model class called CompanyModel which holds an observableList of a Company instance. the Company is a bean holding another observableList of a bean of Product.

i was able to observe a list change event(add/remove) via:

```
companyModel.loadedCompanyList.addListener(new ListChangeListener(){ // do something});
```

and the Company class looks like :

```
class Company {
    private ObservableList<Product> loadedProducts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObjectProperty<Product> currentProduct = new SimpleObjectProperty<Product>();

   // setters and getters
}
```

and the CompanyModel class looks like :

```
class CompanyModel {
    private ObservableList<Company> loadedCompanyList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObjectProperty<Company> selectedCompany = new SimpleObjectProperty<Company>();

   // setters and getters
}
```

The problem is that whenever i add new products in loadedProducts, the binded loadedCompanyList list change event never fires. How can i bind to list item change event of an observablelist?

I indeed googled some answers, here is what i tried:
Changing CompanyModel class into:

```
Callback<Company, Observable[]> extractor = new Callback<Company, Observable[]>() {

    @Override
    public Observable[] call(Company company) {
        return new Observable[] {company.getLoadedProductsProperty()};
    }
};

private ObservableList<Company> loadedCompanyList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(extractor));
```

however, it isn't working..

Comment: The approach is correct. I don't know what is "Study" in the signature of call of your extractor (maybe this causes the problem?), any other parts seem correct.

Comment: Thx, sorry for typos, but for me the extractor is not working.... do you know any of its possible cause?

Comment: Are you sure that you havent reinitializing "loadedCompanyList" or "loadedProducts" somewhere?

Comment: Oh god!!!, i finally found why this is happening,My brain wasn't functioning today , yes i accidentally changed the loadedCompanyList somewhere in code. Thank you DVarga, you save my day!!!!

Comment: No problem mate, glad to hear it is working ^^